# How to compile python program in cmd without changing directory everytime?

Tags: python, cmd, compilation

I store my Python Programs in `G:\PythonWork` and whenever I try to compile the Python programs using cmd..I need to change the directory ..is there any work that I can Directly compile using "Python filename.py" command.(W/O changing directory)

Comment: Umm, if I understand the question correctly, you can use `python G:\PythonWork\filename.py`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I don't want to write the directory everytime ..can i compile the program only using the "Python filename.py"

Comment: How's that supposed to work? Do you expect python to search your entire hard drive for a file named "filename.py"? Or are you looking for a way to configure python to always look for files in "G:\PythonWork"?

Comment: I am looking for a way that python should always look in the G:\PythonWork directory...because I store my python prgms in that folder.....can this be achieved by adding the directory to environment variables..?

Comment: even if there is a way to make python look for only one directory, it would be so stupid, that we can write a entire book about it. just cd to the directory and then run python there. or save ur stuff in your home dir. Nowadays questions are like, why would you even want to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own .bat script to do this such as `dopy.bat` and place it into any directory that is already in your `PATH` variable.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "EXITCODE=0"
PUSHD G:\PythonWork

python "%~1"
SET "EXITCODE=%ERRORLEVEL%"

POPD
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```

Use it by typing the .bat script name and the name of the python file to compile.

```
dopy.bat filename.py
```

This is somewhat simplistic, but it would do what you are asking.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried referencing the python script via an absolute path? For example:

```
python \PythonWork\filename.py
```

This command should work when run from any other folder.